# Qual a classe similar a AesCryptoServiceProvider em .NET Core?

Tags: .net, segurança, asp.net-core, .net-core

Estou migrando uma aplicação para .net core e preciso utilizar a `AesCryptoServiceProvider`, que funcionava perfeitamente em outras versões do .NET Framework.

Porém quando utilizar no .NET Core o Visual Studio alerta que não existe essa biblioteca no `System.Security`

Que biblioteca similar utilizar?

Comment: A resposta resolveu o que estava em dúvida? Precisa que algo mais seja melhorado? Acha que é possível aceitá-la agora?

Comment: Mesmo utilizando <PackageReference Include=" System.Security " Version="4.2.3-r4" /> não é possivel utilizar TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider.

Answer (score 1):

Veja se ajuda [baixar esse Nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CoreCompat.System.Security/). [Tem no .NET Core partindo do 2.0](https://apisof.net/catalog/System.Security.Cryptography.AesCryptoServiceProvider).

Precisa ver se seu projeto está referenciando o pacote, algo assim:

```
<PackageReference Include=" System.Security " Version="4.2.3-r4" />
```